# create a new table from a full join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a new table that includes certain columns from two existing tables.  Some columns are in both existing tables, but not all.  The column "unique_number" is in both tables.  What I want is to check if the same unique_number exists in both tables, and if so then make a single row with all of the columns (from both tables) that correspond to that unique_number. If the unique_number is not in both existing tables then I don't care about including that in my new table.

I can do this in SAS, but I am being forced to do this in SQL with little background knowledge of the program.

Comment: Since it is a poor technique to repeat data from other tables, why are you doing this. WHy not just query teh existing tables for your purpose? If you do make a new table, what is your plan for keeping teh data in synch as the data changes?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds that you need an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `FULL JOIN`. This is a way of doing what you want:

```
SELECT  A.unique_number,
        A.col1FromA, -- list the other columns from TableA here
        B.col1FromB -- list the other columns from TableB here
INTO TableC
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.unique_number = B.unique_number
```

Comment: Table C is created in this process?

Comment: @user2448666 Yes, that's what the `INTO TableC` is doing

Answer (score 0):

An inner join on the "unique_number" column should be all you need, if your description is accurate.

```
select t1.unique_number, t1.other_column, t2.something_else
into new_table_name
from one_table t1
inner join other_table t2
on t1.unique_number = t2.unique_number;
```

This glosses over the complication that "some columns are in both tables", and that those columns that are in both tables might have different values. Give some thought to that.

[Select...into syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

Comment: any way to easily make this a new table?

Comment: Updated answer, and added link.